# How to read a file in a <script> balise

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm regulary hurting myself on a problem for a long time : I'm running a WebGL api that use shader codes. Those shaders are stored in  balises in the head part of my html page like this :

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
[vertex shader code here...]
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
[fragment shader code here...]
</script>
```

But I don't like to have my GLSL code directly in my html page. So I would like to make the following to work :

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex" src="path/to/shader/file.vert"></script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment" src="path/to/shader/file.frag"></script>
```

And give to each shader his own file, with just his path in the html script balise.

But, how can I reach the file from a javascript code once my page is loaded ? I know I will have to use a `FileReader` object to read it, and I know how to use it, but I don't know how reach the `File` objects corresponding to my shader's source files, even when I get the complete path in a string.

I don't want to make an Ajax request, because I don't want to make any more request on the server once my page is loaded.

Please tell me how to open the file from his path... Or if what I'm trying to do here is just impossible.

Comment: you don't use a FileReader for this, you just need ajax. you'll need to fetch the src atrib's URL, and push the response into the html script tag before the other script looks at the tags and finds them to be empty.

Comment: I don't want to use Ajax, because I don't want to make any more request to my server once my page is fully loaded. The shader is a script as others JavaScript files are, Is there any way that they could be transmitted to the client as the .js files are ?

Comment: @Aracthor when you have a script type other than text/javascript the client will not make the request to the server anyway, so it's not causing additional requests.

Comment: no, it's not just a script, it's a syntax error as far as JS goes, and only valid JS can be externally linked. both a real external tag and ajax make an http request, so you're not saving or taxing anything by using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to make an AJAX GET HTTP request to the file:

```
function getShader(id){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ // return a future
       var script = document.getElementById(id).src;
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
       xhr.onload = function(){ resolve(xhr.responseText); };
       xhr.onerror = reject;
       xhr.open("GET", script);
       xhr.send(); 
   });
}
```

Which would in turn let you do:

```
getShader("vertex-shader").then(function(content){
    // content is the contents of the file.
});
```

You can also walk the DOM and put all shaders in a map similarly:

```
function loadAllShaders(){ 
  var shaders = document.querySelectorAll('[type="x-shader/x-vertex"]');
    var futures = [], names = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < shaders.length; i++){
       futures.push(getShader(shaders[i].id));
       names.push(shaders[i].id);
    }

    return Promise.all(shaders).then(function(results){
        var obj = {};
        names.forEach(function(name, i){
           obj[name] = results[i];
        });
        return obj;
    });
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
loadAllShaders().then(function(map){
    map["fragment-shader"]; // contains the content of the shader
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is really no way to get a file without sending an additional HTTP request ? I may have many shaders used on one page, so I could make decades of request like this... It looks heavy.

Comment: @Aracthor when you have a `script` tag, even for a JS script the browser gets it by making an HTTP request - when you have a script tag with a specific type other than text/javascript the browser won't make the request on its own - so you do it instead. This approach in this answer makes as many requests as necessary and no more. In production you _should_ have a build set up (with gulp for example) with minification and concatenation in place so it'd only make a single HTTP request.

Comment: how could one get a remote file without a request? that's not a JS problem, it's a physics problem. the easiest way to avoid those "extra" requests is to simply put the content inline like it originally was delivered.